# CompactFlash card for SD 702

Tags: compact-flash-cards, 702

hi everybody!

Is there any reason why this CF card (http://www.pretec.com/products/memory-cards/item/cf/233x-series) is NOT working with SD 702 ? It gives 'drive offline' message when I try to format. I've checked the card in a store where I bought it and it worked just fine on Windows Xp. but neither SD 702 nor any of my machines at home (windows 7 and mac) recognize it.

Comment: wanted to know if you found a solution to this problem i bought an 8gb SanDisk Extreme CompactFlash and am getting "drive offline" message when I try to format the CompactFlash card. Thank!
~reN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would suggest is to check for any firmware updates for the 702.

As far as compact flash cards for recorders, not all cards are created equally. There are certain brands that, for some reason, just don't work well in devices like the Sound Devices 7 series or the Zaxcom Deva/Fusion series (I've heard of issues with Lexar brand, for instance).

I use Sandisk, and have never had any issues. If a firmware update does not eliminate the problem, you may want to try a different brand.

Comment: I though of firmware update but I need a working card (or firewire disc, which I don't have) to perform it! I'll try Sandisk... thx!

Comment: +1. I've also never had a problem with Sandisk CF cards with any device, including the 702!

Comment: +1 Sandisk are the only one's a buy, even for SDHC cards.  Compared to others they definitely come at a premium price, but extremely worth that extra price premium.  And they invented the CF format too.